# Run djvulibre on iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, djvu

Is it possible to run the djvulibre on iPhone. What should I do for XCode to use the lib? For example, to load the document.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no lawyer, and I've never really understood the differences between all the different licences, but the [DjVuLibre](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/) is under the [GPL license](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html). From the best I can gather, this is in conflict with the licensing requirements that Apple imposes on your application when you submit it to the store. [This thread](http://sourceforge.net/projects/djvu/forums/forum/103286/topic/4044481) provides a little more detail. [Even more detail](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/01/09/the-gpl-the-app-store-and-you/).